# Association Callback Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, callback, has-many

I understand the concept of normal callbacks and association callbacks, i.e when to use which. What I'm puzzled with is what're the possible reasons to prefer normal ones over association callbacks ? I've recently been presented with a situation where I have to go with the former, I want to know why. Are there any performance issues with association callbacks ? I was using after_add in a has_many relationship, to which now I'll be using after_update. Thanks.

Comment: I found [this link](http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/12/01/functions-to-call-upon-activerecord-association-callbacks/) which may be helpful

Comment: @hypern Maybe a little bit. But doesn't exactly answer my doubt. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the reason. When you define an action via Association callbacks, they're only triggered when the object is modified using them.
For ex, if I have 2 models, User and UserRating, with a relationship like ,

```
class User
  has_many :user_ratings
end
```

and I have defined

```
has_many :user_ratings, after_add :do_something
```

This will only be triggered if I follow the object creation path,

```
user.user_ratings.create()
```

But if I simply try a,

```
UserRating.create
```

the callback won't be triggered. Same goes for other association callbacks.